# Is it possible to use Rita's and Andy Crowe's books to prepare for the CAPM exam?

Tags: pmp, education, books, pmi-framework

I've bought the two books mentioned above to prepare for the **PMP** exam until I have the **required conditions** (3+ years of PM work) fulfilled.

I've recently had a look at the **CAPM** exam however, and thought it can't really hurt to sit another test.

My question is this: **Can I use the two book I have to prepare for CAPM? *I.e.* Is CAPM's syllabus a subset of PMP's?**

EDIT: Those books I mentioned are the two best-selling PMP preparation Books. Those are :

- The PMP Exam: How to Pass on your First Try :Crowe, Andy
- [PMP Exam Prep, Seventh Edition: Rita's Course in a Book for Passing the PMP Exam](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1932735410): Mulcahy, Rita

Comment: Can you be more specific, perhaps by posting links to the books you're referring to?  Suppose the authors also wrote books about other topics?  There could also be some books by the author that are not good choices and others that are.  Including specifics in your question will prevent it from being closed by the community and will also ensure you get the high-quality answers you are looking for.  I suggest you make the necessary edits to your question to avoid closure.  Please check out the [FAQ](http://pm.stackexchange.com/faq) for more information on writing great questions.

Comment: You can also check out [Tips for Writing Great Questions](http://meta.pm.stackexchange.com/q/77/34)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundementally the CaPM and PMP test on the same information, that being your knowledge and understanding of the PMI Body of Knowledge (PMBoK).

I used Rita's exam prep when I studied for my PMP and her approach to training will give you a strong basis in the main principles of the PMBoK.

Doing a little digging, I found a Blog that compared the test break downs. [Based on this blog](http://www.projectsmart.co.uk/what-is-the-difference-between-the-capm-and-pmp-examinations.html), I would say that a PMP prep book will more than prepare you for a CaPM.

Stepping away from fact, to offer a small opinion. Unless you are planning to go on to get the PMP, I wouldn't recommend just getting the CaPM. At least in Silicon Valley, I've seen it equated to "Junior Project Management" skills. While this is not the case, I think there is much more value in pushing for the PMP. Remember, almost anything can be a project. As long as someone can vouch for you, then organizing a bake sale can be a project.

Answer (score 2):

PMBOK is always being approached and recommended for both CAPM and PMP. Perhaps, many people found that Rita's PMP guide is quite useful and juicy, it will be like a suppliment. 
CAPM is not difficult in terms of examination and all questions will be straightforward as they assume that you don't have any practcal experience in the managerial line. One personal advice I want to provide you to **Do not attemp too many mock test**, there are almost 1+ million PMP/CAPm questions are floating on the net. Rahter, you should attemp a test and see where and why you have mistaken while giving an the answer. Last but not least, do not forget to read PMBOK at least once to make sure that you are doing what you are expected to do.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would suggest reading PMBOK5 thoroughly. PMBOK5 is dry but its advisable that you go through it entirely without missing out on anything. For reference materials, you can refer Rita Mulcahy exam prep. Many people find it easy to prepare from this book. Also, I would recommend taking an online training- the audio video chapters helps in better understanding of the concepts and you remember the concepts for a long time. There are practice tests included in the training which you can take to understand your knowledge gaps in a much better way hence helping you in gaining confidence.
I feel that you must take more practice tests as it helps a lot. I took my training from [Simplilearn](http://www.simplilearn.com/project-management/capm-certification-training-online/ppa81) and it really helped. Best of Luck!!

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend Andy Crowe reading vs Rita. He is by far more insightful and truly a thought leader in PM. Also, further reading,his book"Alpha Project Managers", a longitudinal study on how 36 of 856 Pm's assessed significantly  outperformed their peers.