# Can I use the PMP Exam book to prep for a CAPM exam?

Tags: pmp, pmbok, pmi-framework, capm

I purchased Rita Mulcahy's PMP Exam Prep(8th Edition) and I have already finished the first eight chapters. However, I have realised that this book is only for experienced PMP attendants not for CAPM. But I'm going to take CAPM exam on 24th June and now I'm pretty stressed and sad.

Should I buy the same writer's CAPM Exam Prep Book or go on with PMP Book?

The problem is simulation exams. Even these exams are gonna be useless for me I think. Instead of studying PMBOK Guide can I take the exam?

Helpful links for mock exams for CAPM could be great as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to use Rita's and Andy Crowe's books to prepare for the CAPM exam?](http://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1147/is-it-possible-to-use-ritas-and-andy-crowes-books-to-prepare-for-the-capm-exam)

Answer (score 1):

If you studied this book and are passing the tests with a reasonable score, you will / should pass the CAPM quite easily.